# How often do we use the "future perfect continuous" in everyday conversation?

Tags: future, speech, perfect-aspect

Consider the following usage

> I will have eaten pizza by 5pm
>   I will have been eating pizza

How often do we use this type of grammatical structure?

Honestly, I have never heard anyone using it :-(

Comment: Rare in comparison to 'will eat', but the future perfect does occur in English in more formal speech. [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+eat%2C+will+have+eaten%2Cwill+have+been+eating%2Cwill+have+been+eaten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) gives links to examples many of which are examples in grammar books. So to the casual user of English, the future perfect is somewhat theoretical.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples sound peculiar because you are using these constructions to talk about activities which few people would ever want (or need) to describe in this manner. This is because they are too trivial to require being specified in such detail.

Contrast your examples with the following:

> I will have finished your report by 5 p.m.
>
> By 4 p.m., I will have been writing that report for nine straight hours.

I think you'll agree that when the constructions you asked about are used to describe a more consequential situation, they sound much more natural.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to understand that constructs invented for complex situations don't seem to be needed in simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20have%20done%20%2Cwill%20have%20been%20doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20have%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20have%20been%20doing%3B%2Cc0) for the two forms of the so-called future continuous of DO show that the continuous form is much less common than the non-continuous. Ngrams for other verbs show similar results.